# AFCI trips when adjacent breaker is switched on

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, afci

[image]I added 2 separate circuits to a small space on the first floor.

Both circuits were AFCI/GFI protected in the breaker panel.

Both circuit home runs ran to one junction box before splitting.

1st circuit was 20A single gang outlet, nothing else.

2nd circuit was 15A for direct wired radiant heater (line thermostat controlled) that would draw max 6A.

All grounds were connected in the junction box.

After consultation with the heater/thermostat company I learned that AFCI/GFI breaker cannot be used with the thermostat.  It requires a conventional breaker.
Conventional 15A breaker installed for the 2nd circuit.

Problem

circuit 1 trips immediately when circuit 2 breaker is switched on.

Circuit 1 does not trip with circuit 2 breaker off and vice versa.  (Btw before switching from AFCI to conventional style 2nd breaker only worked if 1st breaker off and vice versa)

Heater (2nd circuit) works fine as long as other breaker is off.

Outlet (1st circuit) works fine as long as other breaker is off.

Eaton breaker panel and Eaton br115 and Eaton All-in-one 20A breakers.

I’m open to all suggestions to resolve.

Thanks very much

Comment: Can you take a picture of the wiring in the junction box where they split?

Comment: Yes, can you post a photo of the wiring in the junction box where the two circuit splits?

Comment: I can take pic but not sure about upload.  Will work on it

Comment: Smells like crossed neutrals or a neutral to ground short, but more like crossed neutrals.

Comment: > All grounds are connected in the junction box  *You didn't mention neutrals. What about those?*

Comment: Not crossed neutrals but interconnected neutrals,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading 2 breakers to AFCI, always trips](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122795/upgrading-2-breakers-to-afci-always-trips)

Comment: Opened jxn box to take pic. Neutrals are NOT crossed and are separate connections.                   See attached pic. 

There was damage to the wires from the Sheetrock guys so had to wrap neutral in white electrical tape and also use in-sure connectors due to shortened hot.  Visually inspected insulation on the hots and neutrals and can’t see any breaks or bare spots.

Comment: You guys are the frickin greatest.....   No crossed neutrals in the Jxn box but...... what about in the Breaker panel.  Aha    Problem solved.   
I feel shame and sadness.  Try to be sooooo careful and still muck things up.

Answer (score 7):

Neutrals were crossed in the breaker panel.  AFCI is happy now.

Many many thanks  to everyone who took a few seconds from their busy day to help me.

Comment: Glad you were able to lick it!